# I would like to know the reason for the terminal output for this code in an exam question for C

Tags: c

The code is taken from an exam question which I did not know the answer for:

```
int c = 0;

while (c < 5)
{
    if (c == 2)
    {
        continue;
    }

    printf ("data %d", ++c);
}
```

I know that it prints nothing, but I would like to know why?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: run it on paper step by step

Comment: @Ballen Abdullah There is an infinite loop.:) The output will be data 1data 2

Comment: I ran it in a compiler and it prints nothing. I thought it would be data 1data 2 as well, but that wasn't the case. I don't know why it prints absolutely nothing. Shouldn't it at least print data 1?

Comment: I would think `data 1data 2`, but it might be stuck in the output buffer.

Comment: After printf, try fflush(stdout); see what happens..

Comment: After the printf line, add `fflush(stdout);` to make sure that it is actually printed before the program continues. That way, you can be sure not to have any buffering issues.

Comment: Put a `\n` at the end of the format string, or an `fflush(stdout)` after the `printf` if you want to see the output. Otherwise, the output ends up in the output buffer, and stays there because the code goes into an infinite loop.

Comment: If you put at `++c;` right before the `continue;`, it will fix the infinite loop. Then the flush is pretty much moot, since the output buffer will be flushed when the program ends. I get `data 1data 2data 4data 5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some buffering issues. If you add `fflush(stdout)` after the `printf`, you get `data 1data 2`. It doesn't go further than data2 because once `c` is equal to 2, it will keep hitting the if case and skipping the increment. Try the following and you will get `data 1data 2`:

```
int c = 0;

while (c < 5)
{
    if (c == 2)
    {
        continue;
    }
    printf ("data %d", ++c);
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, on POSIX systems, `stdout` is a buffered stream which will only flush when it hits a line feed or when it's explicitly asked to flush using `fflush(stdout);`

Add `fflush(stdout);` after the `printf()` call and then your program should output:

```
data 1data 2
```

After that, your program will be stuck in an infinite loop, because the condition in your `while` statement will always be evaluated to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Once `c == 2` is true, then you will stay in the loop and keep hitting the if statement. So you'll never increment once `c` is set to 2.

```
int c = 2;
if(c == 2) {
    continue;
}
printf("%d", c); // this will never get hit once c is 2 since continue will 
//make the program jump to the next iteration of the loop.
//Also by not flushing after the print, you aren't clearing the buffer and are then not accepting the next print.
```

You don't need to `fflush(stdout)` if the infinite loop is fixed though.